# How can i do search filter on vue js 2.5.16?

Tags: javascript, search, vue.js, filter

I need a search filter in my vue project. I tried to create "text in texts | filterBy filtername" but this isn't working for latest version vue js. Please help!

Comment: Can you please share what you have done yet?

Answer (score 0):

you **cant** use the filters in that way, you **can** use the filter in this way: 
in the **html** : {{ prop | filter}}

in **js** : this.$options.filters.yourFilter(this.prop);

in **html prop** : :text="this.$options.yourFilter(prop);"

Comment: Can I do for another way, without filter?

Comment: if the object is an array you can filter with array.prototype.filter (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)